# Make R print a Stata command

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

```
old <- c("a", "b b", "c")
new <- c("1", "2", "3")
combined <- setNames(new, old)
```

I would like to be able to convert this in the following format:

```
a 1 b b 2 c 3
```

Most importantly, I want to be able to print the output to console (or copy it from a cell), so that I can copy it. The reason is that I need to run something in Stata. The Stata syntax is as follows:

```
coeflabels(mpg Milage rep78 "Repair Record")
```

Stata: coeflabels(name label [...]) specifies labels for the coefficients.
Specify names and labels in pairs and, if necessary, enclose labels in
double quotes, e.g. coeflabels(mpg Milage rep78 "Repair Record".

If at all possible I would like to be able to reproduce produce the following output:

```
a 1 "b b" 2 c 3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rbind` on the `names` and *combined* and bring it to a vector with `c`. Hope the additional `"` are not a problem.

```
c(rbind(names(combined), combined))
#[1] "a"   "1"   "b b" "2"   "c"   "3"
```

Or using `cat` without *[1]* and without `"`:

```
cat(rbind(names(combined), combined), "\n")
#a 1 b b 2 c 3
```

or adding `"` where there is a space:

```
tt <- rbind(names(combined), combined)
i <- grep(" ", tt)
tt[i] <- paste0("\"", tt[i], "\"")
cat(tt, "\n")
#a 1 "b b" 2 c 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am checking if Stata accepts the quotation marks everywhere. Do you know if it is possible to print without `[1]`?

Comment: The solution is absolutely amazing, thank you very much!